# Do Venture-Captain Sayrin Fyrewine or the Gristmill lodge appear in any published Pathfinder adventures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, lore, golarion

I'm looking for information about VC Sayrin Fyrewine and her Pathfinder Lodge in Gristmill. I can find cursory mentions of them on the Pathfinder Wiki [here](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Sayrin_Firewyne) and [here](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Gristmill). Those descriptions seem to be taken from *Seekers of Secrets* and *Guide to the River Kingdoms*, but I was hoping for a little more detail. Do they appear in any PFS scenarios or other published adventures?

Answer (score 1):

### Probably not, but there is one to check

There is a list of [River Kingdom Adventures](https://paizo.com/store/pathfinder/adventures/first/adventureFinder/byRegion/theRiverKingdoms), and searching them for [Uringen](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Uringen) (in the [Embeth Forest](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Embeth_Forest)), there is one that stands out: Year of the Serpent (2015-2016) PFS Scenario 07-02 "[Six Seconds to Midnight](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Six_Seconds_to_Midnight)" which *is* set in Uringen. The only other adventure even remotely nearby is one of the six [Silverhex Chronicles](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/The_Silverhex_Chronicles#Silverhex) which takes place in Gralton, a bit outside of Embeth.

Unfortunately, I don't own either product to see if there are any useful references... but I feel that if they were, they would be at least *referenced* in the wiki for Fyrewine, Gristmill, Uringen, or Embeth Forest (although I suspect the Six Seconds scenario involves investigating the "unstuck" portion of Uringen). Instead, every reference to Fyrewine's existence is referenced to the Seeker of Secrets guidebook.

The others range from halfway to all the way across the River Kingdoms; Fortune's Blight - Sevenarches, You Have what you Hold, Tymon; Emerald Spire, near Fort Inevitable.